# Is there any Adobe Flash Alternative which runs Actionscript 3 on Browser?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, flash, plugins, adobe

I am an Engineering student and due to this pandemic, I was asked to do a virtual simulation of a lab.

https://vem-iitg.vlabs.ac.in/Experiment_DC.html .

I am using a ubuntu 20.4 machine and I use both Chrome and firefox. Theabovelinkis the simulation and It runs by adobe flash and hence unable to access it. I have used ruffle but ruffle doesn't support action scripts 3 which is why I am unable to click buttons and all on the ruffle emulated page.

Please help me with a way to get this work on my browser. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can still install Adobe Flash Player (**warning - it is EOL and insecure**) using some archive links and hacks:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/20380719/+files/flashplugin-installer_32.0.0.465ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./flashplugin-installer_32.0.0.465ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb

sudo wget -c http://mx-linux-packages.mirror.globo.tech/mx/repo/pool/non-free/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20200311.1.orig.tar.gz -O /var/cache/flashplugin-installer/adobe-flashplugin.tar.gz

sudo /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/install_plugin adobe-flashplugin.tar.gz
```

then pin its version to prevent upgrades by using single long command:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-flash
Package: flashplugin-installer
Pin: version 32.0.0.465ubuntu0.20.04.1
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

Then install

- local **old insecure** version of Waterfox (Firefox fork) browser:

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget -c https://cdn.waterfox.net/releases/linux64/installer/waterfox-G3.2.3.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
  tar -xf waterfox-G3.2.3.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
  sudo chown -R root:root waterfox/ # prevent auto-update (optionally)
  cd waterfox/

  ./waterfox https://vem-iitg.vlabs.ac.in/Experiment_DC.html
  ```
- local **old insecure** version of Firefox ESR 52.9.0 [from FTP](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.9.0esr/linux-x86_64/en-US/):

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget -c https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.9.0esr/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-52.9.0esr.tar.bz2
  tar -xf firefox-52.9.0esr.tar.bz2
  sudo chown -R root:root firefox/ # prevent auto-update (optionally)
  cd firefox/

  ./firefox https://vem-iitg.vlabs.ac.in/Experiment_DC.html
  ```

and enjoy.

Comment: This worked for an 'old' Ubuntu 20.04 installtion, but for a completely new one. I get a problem with `sudo /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/install_plugin adobe-flashplugin.tar.gz` I get `sudo: /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/install_plugin: command not found`

Comment: Above problem (`sudo: /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/install_plugin: command not found`) solved with `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Comment: Can't reproduce mentioned errors on fresh 20.04 LTS Docker container. Flash Plugin is installed normally.

Comment: Looks like the fourth command now throws a 404 error when it tries to download the tar.gz file from archive.canonical.com