# Adobe Connect requires Flash Player 11.2 or above

Tags: 20.04, firefox, google-chrome, flash

I'm trying to access Adobe connect, but it gives me following error:

> Adobe Connect requires Flash Player 11.2 or above.

However I tested it on Firefox and Chrome, also I have installed Flash player using this command:

```
$ sudo apt install flashplugin-installer
```

But it showed me the same error in Firefox, so I test it on Chrome and again nothing positive happened.

What's wrong with this? How can I fix it?

(As you know, I can't even download something from officaial Adobe site, because they end developing flash)

Comment: Please use the current and supported version of Adobe Connect that DOESN'T require flash.

Comment: @ChanganAuto But I can't do it, the manager who create and manage rooms has selected this one, Not any other way?

Comment: Flash is as good as dead, period. So, that's something you may want to discuss with "the manager" and/or contact Adobe for a solution because this is a commercial product. What doesn't make sense is asking random people on the internet.

Comment: @Sina They can want it. But **Adobe Flash is dead**. They can wish for this one, but Flash has been removed from all modern browsers because it is a security issue, and Adobe has deprecated it. Yes, it is technically possible to use Flash in certain situations (like in a VM), but it is a big security risk, so you shouldn't.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1347319/66509), but yes flash is dead.

Comment: Adobe officially killed Flash player on December 31, 2020. All major browsers too removed Flash support either at the same time or in early 2021. With Flash support ending, websites that offer Flash-based content like games and animations have no choice but to remove them too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general solution for this, but the workaround to play adobe connect in web is to concat value of `urlPath` parameter with main domain, then add a new parameter `proto` for new url and set it to **true**.

For example

```
https://example.com/system/get-player?urlPath=/pzcgmf009dyq/
```

Becomes...

```
https://example.com/pzcgmf009dyq?proto=true
```

Now it works fine.