# How to install the Flash player

Tags: 20.04, firefox, chromium, flash

I have been desperately looking for a way to install flash player on Firefox or Chromium but the tutorials on all the websites that I saw were useless. They all redirect to the Adobe website which says Flash player has reached the end of its life. Unfortunately on the website of my university they use this antiquated tech that has gone extinct and now I really need to find a way to install it.
Also, the Ruffle extension for Firefox does not open the class session. It gets stuck on starting the session.

Comment: You may want to get in touch with your university and ask them how to view it, then, as Flash is nowhere to be downloaded. If you can find *a really old version of Chrome*, then Google's implementation will be in place, but it'll need to be from many, many years ago ...

Comment: Flash is gone quite a while ago. You are trying to install something that currently does not exist.

Comment: Flash is really dead. But you can use the method which is described in the following my answer - https://askubuntu.com/a/1347319/66509 . It works even today with Waterfox and Firefox 52.9.0 ESR.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks. I'll try it.